# Add additional packages to catkin_ws?

Tags: ros, catkin, beaglebone, ros-groovy, catkin-ws

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been working on getting ROS Groovy on a BeagleBone. Following the instructions on installing Groovy from source (http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Source) (there are a few errors in this) I can build the catkin workspace with different variants just fine.

As I only need the BeagleBone for interfacing sensors remotely to my ROS PC I'm working mainly with the bare bones variant (ROS-Comm). I tried the Robot variant as it has the additional packages I need but there are erros with collada (and I don't need collada and several other packages that come with Robot so I'm starting with ROS-Comm).

Now my question: After the catkin workspace is built, how do you build new packages into the existing catkin ws?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62143/add-additional-packages-to-catkin_ws?/) by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on ROS Answers with karma: 160 on 2013-05-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Add them to the `src/` subdirectory and re-run `catkin_make`.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on 2013-05-06**:
It appears these can be added after the variant and before rosdep, or after rosdep as well (but does rosdep need to be run again??).

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-05-06**:
@TJump if you have new packages then they might have new system dependencies, so yes you need to run `rosdep`... Otherwise their dependencies might not be met and their build might fail.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-05-06**:
The other thing you can do is create another catkin workspace on top of the current workspace you have. This might be more efficient depending on your use case.